# How to handle not used functions from delegates in view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, delegation

I have a very general view that is created and used by multiple view controllers with 2 buttons, one of them sometimes is hidden depending on the needs.
This view delegates the tap of the two buttons.

```
protocol TheViewsDelegate: class { 
     func button1Tapped()
     func button2Tapped()
}
```

Let's put that ViewControllerA creates this view and needs both buttons, this view controller will have to implement both delegate functions and do something inside it.

Now let's say that ViewControllerB creates the same view but just needs one of the buttons. This view controller will have to still implement `button2Tapped()` even though it will never be called and used.

Is there a way to handle this nicely? I imagine there's a nice solution where I don't need to implement this `button2Tapped()` if I don't need it.

I thought about making it optional by giving a default implementation but I don't like this solution, I like (and I think it's a good practice) the compiler giving me an error when a method it's not implement. Someone can jump into the project and not realising that he/she hasn't implement button2Tapped when needs to be implemented.

**Note**: This is a very simple example just to illustrate my question, but the question is more broad as in what to do when a function in a delegate is defined by controller that don't need to implement it.

Comment: Yet, `optional` is used in UITableView (Delegate/Datasource), for instance: `optional func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int`. Now, could you maybe combine theses two delegate method? like `func buttonTapped(_button:UIButton) -> Void`, if the user have access to the buttons, or use `func buttonTapped(SomeIntegerActionEnumOrClosure) -> Void`?

Comment: @Larme it's true that ```optional``` is used by Apple but I am wondering if it's the good way to go. For how I see it, ```optional``` brings risks into the code, other developers might not know they have to implement it and will fail silently. Having the empty methods in the view controllers is "just" ugly, but it's safer in my opinion.

Comment: So I'd go from the small piece of info you gave `func buttonTappedForAction(action: actionEnum)`. Then, developer can decide if they want to manage all the actions with a switch case?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to use:

optional func

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways of declaring a protocol method as optional, one  is using `optional func` which requires using `@objc` syntax, which a lot of programmers apparently don't like, and the other requires declaring an empty body in the extension of a protocol (which makes it optional by default).

```
protocol TheViewsDelegate: AnyObject {
    func button1Tapped()
}
extension TheViewsDelegate {
    func button2Tapped() {}
}

class SomeViewController: UIViewController, TheViewsDelegate {
    func button1Tapped() {
        // implement
    }
}
```

By giving the protocol an empty body inside an extension of the protocol, that method is optional and does not need to be implemented by conforming objects.

For comparison, the alternative:

```
@objc protocol TheViewsDelegate: AnyObject {
    func button1Tapped()
    @objc optional func button2Tapped()
}

class SomeViewController: UIViewController, TheViewsDelegate {
    func button1Tapped() {
        // implement
    }
}
```